# How to check if int value exist in a dataTable

Tags: c#

How can check if the value exist in datatable column (int)

For example, I search if "9" exist in the column named "entryHour".

```
bool exists = listAgenda.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.Field<string>("entryHour").Equals(9)).Count() > 0;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you describe what problem you are experiencing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have integer type field in database then try this

```
bool exists = listAgenda.AsEnumerable().Any(c => c.Field<int>("entryHour") == 9));
```

But if you have string type then need to cast into integer first

```
bool exists = listAgenda.AsEnumerable().Any(c => int.Parse(c.Field<string>("entryHour")) == 9));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing between a string and int values. You need to compare apples with apples.

```
bool exists = listAgenda.AsEnumerable().Any(c => c.Field<string>("entryHour") == "9");
```